# Customizable/Themable UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, customization

I would like to offer my users the ability to customize the look and feel of the website.

I am giving them a color picker to choose a color scheme. I would like to dynamically generate few matching colors and apply them.

My questions are:

1.) How can i generate a color scheme based on the choosen color ? (some matching colors and contrasting colors for the background)

2.) What are the best practices for achieving a themable interface ?

I am writing an AngularJS SPA app with pure HTML with REST API as backend.

Right now for my 2nd question, I am retrieving the color setting and applying them for body.

```
<body style="background:color:{{bgcolor}}; color:{{fgcolor}}">
```

I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: You can provide a server generated css with customized colors, but why not provide 2-3 color schemes? Allowing the choice of ANY color could be quite a hassle to code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ngStyle as you have above... but as you noted, it's not very elegant.

The simple truth is that nothing in AngularJS itself is really designed to address this problem other than the ngStyle directive itself. However, while I haven't exactly seen a "best practice" for this, you might take some ideas from Drupal's "Color" module, which is one of its base/core modules. You can do the same thing in Angular very easily.

What this does is go back to stylesheets, which I'm assuming you skipped over because it didn't seem like an obvious solution for something dynamic. But they have a clever answer. In a piece of code, after the user picks a color, they write out a stylesheet with a unique ID for its filename. They put these in a directory where other user-uploaded assets are kept, so they don't mix with core site code (minimize the potential attack vector). Then they only need a simple rule in the page to include the stylesheet itself.

You can easily emulate all of this with Angular, although you'll need your server's help, of course. But the nice thing about it is it's much easier for you to maintain. Instead of having to "sprinkle" ngStyle directives all over the place (one on everything you want styled) and potentially having conflicts with other things you want to do on some of those elements, the stylesheet can work exactly the way it's supposed to: using classes to target specific elements. You can make a template stylesheet that's easy to maintain, so that's a natural fit... and the best part is, it's easy to hook everything up.